# Django PATCH request update password using set_password method

Tags: python, django

I have below setup,

**view.py**

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = apis_models.User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = apis_serializers.UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [HasPermPage]
    http_method_names = ['get', 'patch']
```

**Serializer.py**

```
class UserSerializer(CustomSerializer):
    group = GroupSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = apis_models.User
        fields = '__all__'
```

**models.py**

```
class User(DFModel, AbstractBaseUser):
    GENDER_CHOICES = [
        ('m', 'Male'),
        ('f', 'Female'),
        ('n', 'Not sure'),
    ]

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, null=True)
    date_of_birthday = models.DateField(null=True)
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    credit_card = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey('Group', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
```

Using REST API I am doing PATCH request on User model and trying to update the password.
The password is getting stored as plain text.
I found that set_password method store it as encrypted.
Can anybody please help me to implement that. I am not sure where to include that method. In viewset or serializer? And how?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override your **`update(...)`** method (and `create` method) of Serializer as,

```
class UserSerializer(CustomSerializer):
    group = GroupSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = apis_models.User
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = super().create(validated_data)

        try:
            user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
            user.save()
        except KeyError:
            pass

        return user

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        user = super().update(instance, validated_data)

        try:
            user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
            user.save()
        except KeyError:
            pass

        return user
```

Comment: Thanks Arakkal for your reply.
I tried this but it is still storing the data in plain text.

Comment: oops....I forgot to add **`user.save()`**. Check my updated answer :)